# Вывод многоуровневого массива в шаблоне blade laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

При попытки прикрутить информер валют на laravel 5.2 столкнулся с проблемой. При выводе получаю ошибку Undefined index: USD (View:.......

Вот, что имею в контроллере

```
 public function getNBUCur() {
        // Список валют по умолчанию
        define('_DEFOUT','USD.EUR.RUB',true);
    // Проверяем наличие параметра
    if (isset($_GET['out'])){ 
            if (ctype_alnum(str_replace('.','',$_GET['out']))){
               define('_GETOUT',$_GET['out'],true);
            }  
        }       
    define('_VALOUT',(defined('_GETOUT')?_GETOUT:_DEFOUT),true);

    // Получаем курсы на текущую дату
    $NBUDoc = simplexml_load_file('http://bank-ua.com/export/currrate.xml');
    $NBUDat = [];

    // Пихаем всё в ассоциативный массив
    foreach ($NBUDoc->children() as $NBUItem){
            $charCode = strval($NBUItem->char3);
            $result = [
                'date'  => strval($NBUItem->date),
                'char3'  => strval($NBUItem->char3),
                'name'  => strval($NBUItem->name),
                'size'  => strval($NBUItem->size), 
                'rate'  => strval($NBUItem->rate),
                'change' => strval($NBUItem->change)
            ];

            $NBUDat[$charCode] = $result;
            $this->data['NBUDat'] = $NBUDat[$charCode];
        }

        // Выводим таблицу         
    $_TOOUT = explode('.', _VALOUT);
        $this->data['_TOOUT'] = $_TOOUT;      

        return view('components.informer', $this->data);  

}
```

В шаблоне:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <b>НБУ</b>
                <td>Курс к UAH</td>
                <td>Курс НБУ</td>
                <td>Динамика</td>
                <td>Дата</td>                       
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($_TOOUT as $_KEY => $_VAL)
                    <tr>
                        <td class='ccy'>{{ $NBUDat[$_VAL]['char3'] }}</td>
                        <td class='buy'>{{ $NBUDat[$_VAL]['rate'] }}</td>
                        <td class='change'>{{ $NBUDat[$_VAL]['change'] }}</td>
                        <td class='date'>{{ $NBUDat[$_VAL]['date'] }}</td>  
                    </tr>                    
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Если кто-то может, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне это исправить.

В отдельном файле код работает как положено. Работает и в laravel, если весь код поместить в контроллер, а в шаблоне просто вызвать этот метод. Я решил попробовать разделить этот код, чтобы таблица выводилась в шаблоне, а не в контроллере... и тут застрял.

Answer (score 1):

Удалите внутри цикла строчку

```
$this->data['NBUDat'] = $NBUDat[$charCode];
```

и вместо нее после цикла напишите

```
$this->data['NBUDat'] = $NBUDat;
```

То есть ваш контроллер будет таким:

```
public function getNBUCur()
{
    // Список валют по умолчанию
    define('_DEFOUT', 'USD.EUR.RUB', true);
    // Проверяем наличие параметра
    if (isset($_GET['out']))
    {
        if (ctype_alnum(str_replace('.', '', $_GET['out'])))
        {
            define('_GETOUT', $_GET['out'], true);
        }
    }
    define('_VALOUT', (defined('_GETOUT') ? _GETOUT : _DEFOUT), true);

    // Получаем курсы на текущую дату
    $NBUDoc = simplexml_load_file('http://bank-ua.com/export/currrate.xml');
    $NBUDat = [];

    // Пихаем всё в ассоциативный массив
    foreach ($NBUDoc->children() as $NBUItem)
    {
        $charCode = strval($NBUItem->char3);
        $result = [
            'date' => strval($NBUItem->date),
            'char3' => strval($NBUItem->char3),
            'name' => strval($NBUItem->name),
            'size' => strval($NBUItem->size),
            'rate' => strval($NBUItem->rate),
            'change' => strval($NBUItem->change)
        ];

        $NBUDat[$charCode] = $result;
    }
    $this->data['NBUDat'] = $NBUDat;

    // Выводим таблицу         
    $_TOOUT = explode('.', _VALOUT);
    $this->data['_TOOUT'] = $_TOOUT;

    return view('components.informer', $this->data);
}
```